# Issue with setting a counter inside a class

Tags: python, class, counter

Simple question, but cant figure it out for the life of me. I'm asking trivia question but i want to keep track of correct answers, so I make a counter. Just can't figure where to put without it being reset to 0 or getting a premature reference error.

```
class Questions():
    def __init__(self, question, answer, options):
        self.playermod = player1()
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.options = options
        self.count = 0

    def ask(self):            
        print(self.question + "?")
        for n, option in enumerate(self.options):
            print("%d) %s" % (n + 1, option))

        response = int(input())
        if response == self.answer:
            print("Correct")
            self.count+=1
        else:
            print("Wrong")

questions = [
Questions("Forest is to tree as tree is to", 2, ["Plant", "Leaf", "Branch", "Mangrove"]),
Questions('''At a conference, 12 members shook hands with each other before &
            after the meeting. How many total number of hand shakes occurred''', 2, ["100", "132", "145", "144","121"]),
]
random.shuffle(questions)    # randomizes the order of the questions

for question in questions:
    question.ask()
```

Comment: Put aside your code and come up with the smallest example you can which produces the same kind of error. Give the expected behaviour and actual behaviour, and describe why you can't understand the disparity. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Will do mate. Appreciated.

Comment: Is there only one player per session, or multiple players? If there are multiple players it makes sense for a `count` to be associated with each player, rather than with the questions. BTW, the indentation of the `for` loop in `.ask` is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have separate instance data per `Questions` class instantiation. You can solve this by using a `class` attribute instead.

Essentially you have this:

```
class Question():
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def ask(self):
        self.count += 1
        print(self.count)
```

If you have two different question instances, they will have their own `count` member data:

```
>>> a = Question()
>>> a.ask()
1
>>> a.ask()
2
>>> b = Question()
>>> b.ask()
1
```

What you want is both questions to share the same `count` variable. (from a design standpoint this is dubious, but I take it you're trying to understand the technicalities of the language rather than object oriented design.)

The `Question` class can share data by having a class member rather than instance member data:

```
class Question():
    count = 0

    def ask(self):
        self.count += 1
        print(self.count)

>>> a = Question()
>>> a.ask()
1
>>> b = Question()
>>> b.ask()
2
```

edit: If you wanted to completely separate the score you could have `ask` return the points and then sum them up. Each question could be worth a different amount of points, too:

```
class Question():
    def __init__(points):
        self.points = points

    def ask(self):
        return self.points  # obviously return 0 if the answer is wrong

>>> questions = [Question(points=5), Question(points=3)]
>>> sum(question.ask() for question in questions)
8
```

Comment: Would it help to add all the question to the class and then define a method to access those?

Comment: There are many different directions to take the design. You could have the question return the amount of points scored. Then you can sum in a loop.